# How to import a postman collection into soapui without updating to readyAPI? Because my trial version of readyAPI is already expired

Tags: postman, soapui

How to import a postman collection into soapui without updating to readyAPI?  Because my trial version of readyAPI is already expired. Is there any other way?

Comment: I believe there exist a plugin for the same. Try it.

Comment: See if this helps! https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Import-Postman-Collection/td-p/150269